# Problemas com automação web em VBA - Radio Button

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Olá, Sou novo por Aqui,
Estou enfrentando um problema com meu código VBA, estou tentando uma interação usando a internet explore, preciso que faça os seguintes passos

1. acesse o site: https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/historicocotacoes
2. selecione o radio button 2 <"Cotações de fechamento de todas as moedas em uma data.">
3. clique em pesquisar.

porém, quando tento lecionar o radio button, ele aparece um erro. abaixo está o meu código.

```
    Sub buscador()
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    
    ie.navigate "https://www.bcb.gov.br/estabilidadefinanceira/historicocotacoes"
    ie.Visible = True
    
    Do While ie.Busy And ie.readyState <> ""
    DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ie.document.getElementById("RadOpcao").Item(1).Click
    
    ie.document.getElementsByClassName("fundoPadraoBClaro3").Item(0).getElementsByTagName("input").Item(1).Click
    
    
    End Sub
```

HTML que estou pegando as class

[Imagem do codigo em html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm5wY.png)

Comment: `getElementById` como diz o nome do método pega um elemento, então não precisa do `.Item` pq não vai ter retornar um array mas um único objeto

Comment: @RicardoPontual testei com a seguinte expressão ie.document.getElementsByTagName("RadOpcao")(0).Click  porem não deu certo, deu erro 91

Comment: acredito que não conhece muito de html, acho que precisa dar uma olhada sobre :)  `getElementsByTagName`  vai procurar uma tag como o nome do método diz, eu não conheço uma tag "RadOpcao" no html  :) esse método se usa para "input", "button", "div", etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A URL que está tentando interpretar através do InternetExplorer.application possui um iframe (basicamente uma página dentro de outra página, veja mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)).

Os iframes limitam as seleções e execuções, inclusive as rotinas definidas pelo VBA.

A solução é buscar o acesso diretamente nessa página que está incorporada na página principal. Ao inspecionar a página é possível chegar até ela ([URL base](https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=exibeFormularioConsultaBoletim)), veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora podemos ajustar o código VBA com essa URL. Ainda, alterei as linhas de busca e clique, utilizando [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) a partir do value, que aparentemente é um valor único em cada elemento (o ID dos elementos HTML estão repetidos, o que não é recomendado, podendo gerar algum erro):

```
Sub buscador()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

ie.navigate "https://ptax.bcb.gov.br/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=exibeFormularioConsultaBoletim"
ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.Busy And ie.readyState <> ""
DoEvents
Loop

ie.document.querySelector("input[value='2']").Click
ie.document.querySelector("input[value='Pesquisar']").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: perfeito amigo, deu certo!!

Comment: agora eu estou na parte de "baixar" o arquivo. Vou tentando aqui. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ótimo. Sinaliza como resposta adequada, pode ajudar mais pessoas. Se surgir novos problemas, crie uma nova pergunta para não misturar os temas.